# Memory usage of a given process (using Linux proc filesystem)

Tags: process, memory, proc

I want to know which files from /proc directory and which fields of these files I need to calculate the memory usage of a given pid. I've been using the "stat" file and the "vsize" parameter that is in this file but it isn't a good calculation. Anyone knows a better formula for this? Thanks, Ana.

Comment: You should define precisely what *memory usage* means to you.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Indeed you need to use `/proc/`; so read carefully [proc(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html).

For process 1234 you want to read `/proc/1234/maps` (or `/proc/1234/smaps`) to get the address space, and to read `/proc/1234/status` & `/proc/1234/statm`

For your own process (programmatically) use `/proc/self/maps`, `/proc/self/status`, `/proc/self/statm`

Notice that *memory usage* is a very ambiguous term on Linux. How would you count a file segment `mmap`-ed by two processes? See [mmap(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html) & [getrusage(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/getrusage.2.html)

Try `cat /proc/self/maps`, `cat /proc/$$/maps` in a terminal. Read wikipages on [address space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space), [virtual memory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_memory), [page cache](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Page_cache), [ASLR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization), [ELF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format), [RSS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resident_set_size), [working set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Working_set) ...

Comment: Thanks Basile. I want to calculate a percentage of memory usage. As command "top" calculates. I am coding in C so I will obtain the parameters with fscanf and  I will use the formula that I want then. Thanks.

Comment: Since `top` is a free software, you could study its source code and understand what it is calculating. My point is that *memory usage* is ambiguous and you should define what you want.

Answer (score 4):

Getting `pss` ("proportional set size") in GB:

```
cat /proc/$pid/smaps | grep -i pss |  awk '{Total+=$2} END {print Total/1024/1024" GB"}'
```

Comment: Perfect command that calculate memory usage like top does! Thanks.